# Bonds of a Graph G and it's related statements

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I am referring Diestel's book on Graph Theory 5th Edition.

> Lemma 3.1.3. The following statements are equivalent for distinct
>   edges e, f of a graph G:
>
> (i) The edges e, f belong to a common block of G.
>
> (ii) The edges e, f belong to a common cycle in G.
>
> (iii) The edges e, f belong to a common bond of G.

In the explanation of above lemma, they give the following:

(ii)→(iii) Deleting e and f from a cycle C $\ni$ e, f leaves a partition of V (C) into two connected sets. Extend this to a partitition into two connected sets of the vertex set of the component of G containing C. 
The edges between these sets form a bond of G containing e and f.

How can we proove the statement (iii) from the assumption (ii)? How the above explanation helpful for proving this?

Comment: The portion you cite: (ii)→(iii) *is* the proof given by Diestel. Sometimes Diestel is very terse, but in this case Diestel himself provides the hint (which you've left out). Before the sentence "The edges between these sets..." he asks, parenthetically, "How"? That is: How do you extend this partition thus? Do a little unpacking and you'll see that it does indeed prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an edge from a cycle produces a path. Deleting a second edge from the cycle disconnects the cycle into two components. We let $S$ be the vertex set of one component, and $\overline{S}$ be the vertex set of the other.

A bond is a minimum edge cut, which is the smallest number of edges to disconnect vertex sets $S$ and $\overline{S}$. In the case of a cycle, a bond just so happens to be two edges.

Comment: In the case of a cycle, two edges are okay. But in the case, the cycle itself is a part of a block. In this case, we need some more edge deletion to disconnect that block.  I got the idea behind this, but I am stuck in write a formal proof for this :-( .

Answer (score 0):

Let the common bond be $[S,\overline{S}]$, then $G[S], G[\overline{S}]$ are all connected (referring Theorem 2.15 in Bondy's book Graph Theory) such that there exist two paths connecting two ends of $e$ and $f$, forming a cycle which is what we need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).